# How created multi update query with JPA data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I try to create query setAll , because a entity with top isValid and I want  all value to false before I use saveAll for udpade my database. I use this methods synchronize my database with a batch 6000-7000 lines actually.

```java
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
public interface  DomRepository extends CrudRepository<Dom, String> {

    public Domaine findDomByName(String dom);
    public List<Dom> findAll();
    public void setIsValidAll(boolean isValid);

}
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Dom{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    // more attribute
    private boolean isValid;
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'setIsValidAll' found for type 'Dom'!
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve based on the description you have provided but if I get this right, you would like to create a repository when that will effectively update the value of the `isValid` field for all `Dom` objects. If that is indeed the case then you could simply create a custom repository method that will accept your flag and will make use of a simple HQL or JPQL to update all records in the database. For example something like this could work for this case:

```java
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Dom SET isValid = :valid")
void updateValidAll(boolean valid);
```

If on the other hand you want to perform the update in memory on the fetched entities and then perform a `saveAll` you could do something like this:

```java
@Transactional
public void updateAllRecords2(boolean isValid) {
    var records = repository.findAll()
        .stream()
        .peek(dom -> dom.setValid(isValid))
        .toList();
    repository.saveAll(records);
}
```

Note that the latter is not very optimal as it uses `peek` which should not be used on operations that have side-effects (i.e mutations). On top of that will will perform an update query for every single entity that is present, meaning N queries for N entities.

Comment: i want the first solution but It not possible in JPA ?

Comment: The first solution IS a pure JPA solution. I think you need to familiarise yourself more with the concepts that you are dealing with.